# Change Dimensions on Project

Tags: scale, units, dimensions

can anyone quickly tell me, how can change the dimensions of my whole project. For example: If I am building a skyscraper and it is to big to navigate, it would be much easier to just put in the numbers for the cube at dimensions (20m*20m*100m) and still have a relativeley small object. But if its a bigger project, I wouldn't want to divide every dimension by 100. Is that understandable or do I need to elaborate? :)

Cheers

Comment: Hello :). You can change the scene scale in *Scene Tab > Units > Unit Scale*. I just don't see wshy though, you can always zoom in / zoom out, right? :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer :). Of course i could but at some point of zooming out, blender just doesnt show me any of my meshes anymore. I tried fixing that with the clip option but it didn't work :(

Comment: So actually, if you know how to fix that, that would be of even bigger help :)

Comment: Oh, sure :). The clip option is actually the right thing to adjust. Set Clip End to a higher value. It's 1000m by default which can be too low, just make it 10000m :).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is actually much easier to just adjust the clipping instead of messing around with dimensions. I also found it to be easier to use measureIt, a very convenient tool for architectural modelling...